# Palindrome check not working

Tags: java

```
public class reverse
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a new string : ");
        String word = sc.nextLine();
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= word.length() - 1; i++)
        {
            char c = word.charAt(word.length() - i - 1);
            s.append(c);
        }
        System.out.println("Reversed String = " + s);
        if (word.equals(s))
        {
            System.out.println("This is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("This is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

This always prints "This is not a palindrome" no matter what string I give as input

Answer (score 4):

You'll need

```
if (word.equals(s.toString())){ 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

word is of type `String` and s is of type `StringBuilder` and so they are not equal in terms of types.

it should be

```
if (word.equals(s.toString()) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**invoking toString() on the StringBuilder instance, and then comparing  with equals method**

if (s.toString().equals(word)){

```
}
```

Comment: you guyes are the best! Thanks  a lot :)